# Why does getting Elements from an XDocument result in null?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Can anyone explain to me why **xml1.Element("title")** correctly equals "`<title>Customers Main333</title>`" but **xml2.Element("title")** surprisingly equals **null**, i.e. why do I have to get the XML document as an *element* instead of a *document* in order to pull elements out of it?

```
var xml1 = XElement.Load(@"C:\\test\\smartForm-customersMain.xml");
var xml2 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\test\\smartForm-customersMain.xml");

string title1 = xml1.Element("title").Value;
string title2 = xml2.Element("title").Value;
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<smartForm idCode="customersMain">
    <title>Customers Main333</title> 
    <description>Generic customer form.</description>
    <area idCode="generalData" title="General Data">
        <column>
            <group>
                <field idCode="anrede">
                    <label>Anrede</label>
                </field>
                <field idCode="firstName">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                </field>
                <field idCode="lastName">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </column>
    </area>
    <area idCode="address" title="Address">
        <column>
            <group>
                <field idCode="street">
                    <label>Street</label>
                </field>
                <field idCode="location">
                    <label>Location</label>
                </field>
                <field idCode="zipCode">
                    <label>Zip Code</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </column>
    </area>
</smartForm>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The XDocument **represents the whole document, not the root node**. 
Use `Root` to get the root element.

```
var title = xml2.Root.Element("title").Value;
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

This is because [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) has an outermost layer that requires you to drill past to get to the elements.  An [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) targets the actual element itself.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, many DOM implementations *as a document* have a level *above* the root element, allowing for consistent "Add" etc. You have a reference to this level, no the root element.

When parsing just an element, this isn't necessary or useful, so is omitted.

You should be able to use `.Root` to get the root element.